# ggplot dimensions issue in rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have an `rmarkdown` file. I would like to plot charts two at a time on one column, two rows. The below reproducible example works.

````
---
title: "xx"
author: "xx"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
urlcolor: blue
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results = 'hide'}
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(data=data.frame("d"=1:5))+geom_line(aes(y=d, x=d))

# grid.arrange(p1,p1, nrow = 2, ncol=1)

for(i in 1:3) { # doing this multiple times
  plot(grid.arrange(p1,p1, nrow = 2, ncol=1))
}
  
```
````

[image]

But when I try to specify the `fig.height` and `fig.width` of each plot, the arrangement breaks.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results = 'hide', fig.height = 28/6, fig.width = 20/4.8}

p1 <- ggplot(data=data.frame("d"=1:5))+geom_line(aes(y=d, x=d))

# grid.arrange(p1,p1, nrow = 2, ncol=1)

for(i in 1:3) { # doing this multiple times
  plot(grid.arrange(p1,p1, nrow = 2, ncol=1))
}
  

```
````

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried producing the plot in the console of Rstudio if it works fine before plotting it using Rmarkdown? And also have you tried reducing the height anf width?

Comment: plotting in console seems to work. changing dimensions has no effect *afaik*

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `fig.align="center"` solved the issue.